# Conditionally display items in ListAdapter based on available horizontal space

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a ListAdapter that's using a RelativeLayout to display items in the list.

The layout has a TextView aligned on the right side and I want to display a variable list of ImageView/TextView pairs from the left side based on available space. If one of the pairs would overlap the right aligned text view, I don't want to display any more.

Here are a few images that illustrate:

On a narrow screen, perhaps 2 pairs would display:

[image: narrow list item]

On a wider screen perhaps 4 pairs would display:

[image: wide list item]

I've gone down the road of trying to measure the elements, in the BaseAdapter getView override. But that only measures the text, it doesn't tell me the position. I suppose I also need to call layout as well?

Is there an easier technique I can use?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can design individual layouts for different orientations and size screens, then Android will automatically use the load appropriate layouts for you. Read about how to do this in: [Designing for Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/index.html)

Comment: I'd need something more flexible.  The right aligned and.pair text can be different lengths in the same list. So even on the same device some rows could only show 2 pairs without overlapping others 4.